# OpenVPN very basic configuration for traffic redirecting

Tags: debian, openvpn

I've seen similar questions, but I still don't understand what's wrong with my configuration. I've followed the [debian wiki OpenVPN page](https://wiki.debian.org/OpenVPN) to try to set up a VPN on my VPS. I need to browse the web through my server. Both my client and server are running Debian 9.

On my VPS:

```
root@MYVPS:/etc/openvpn
# cat tun0.conf 
dev tun0
ifconfig 10.9.8.1 10.9.8.2
secret /etc/openvpn/static.key
push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"
push "dhcp-option DNS 208.67.222.222"
push "dhcp-option DNS 208.67.220.220"

root@MYVPS:/etc/openvpn
# cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/tun0/forwarding
1

root@MYVPS:/etc/openvpn
# iptables --list
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all  --  10.9.8.0/24          anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all  --  10.9.8.0/24          anywhere    

root@MYVPS:/etc/openvpn
# ping 10.9.8.2
PING 10.9.8.2 (10.9.8.2) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.9.8.2: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=32.5 ms
```

On my client:

```
ME@MYPC:/etc/openvpn
$ cat tun0.conf 
remote vps
dev tun0
ifconfig 10.9.8.2 10.9.8.1
secret /etc/openvpn/static.key

ME@MYPC:/etc/openvpn
$ ping 10.9.8.1
PING 10.9.8.1 (10.9.8.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.9.8.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=31.9 ms

ME@MYPC:/etc/openvpn
$ ip route list
default via 192.168.0.254 dev eth0 proto static metric 100 
10.9.8.1 dev tun0 proto kernel scope link src 10.9.8.2 
192.168.0.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.0.37 metric 100
```

So I guess that there is something missing in my "routes". The debian wiki indicates to type

```
# ip route add VPNSERVER_IP via LOCALGATEWAY_IP dev eth0  proto static
# ip route change default via 10.9.8.5 dev tun0  proto static   //client tun0 10.9.8.5
```

and I'm not sure what `VPNSERVER_IP` and `LOCALGATEWAY_IP` should be, and why this new ip `10.9.8.5` is here.

Anyway, after a "try and retry with another IP if error message" approach, I managed to add a route using the real public IP of my server and the IP indicated in the first line of `ip route list` (`192.168.0.254`). So now I have this :

```
ME@MYPC:/etc/openvpn
$ ip route list
default via 192.168.0.254 dev eth0 proto static metric 100 
10.9.8.1 dev tun0 proto kernel scope link src 10.9.8.2 
192.168.0.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.0.37 metric 100 
MYSERVERIP via 192.168.0.254 dev eth0 proto static
```

I feel that I'm close, but I cannot `change default`

```
ME@MYPC:/etc/openvpn
$ sudo ip route change default via 10.9.8.5 dev tun0  proto static
RTNETLINK answers: Network is unreachable
ME@MYPC:/etc/openvpn
$ sudo ip route change default via 10.9.8.2 dev tun0  proto static
RTNETLINK answers: No such file or directory
ME@MYPC:/etc/openvpn
$ sudo ip route change default via 10.9.8.1 dev tun0  proto static
RTNETLINK answers: No such file or directory
```

What am I doing wrong ? Thanks for reading me. Networking is not my field *at all*, but I'm trying…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put one line into `tun0.conf` on client:

```
redirect-gateway
```

Comment: Great, thanks ! For the record, I had to use `sudo ip route change default via 10.9.8.1 dev tun0  proto static`.

Comment: `redirect-gateway` option should do that; no  need for manually change routing.

Comment: Indeed, debian wiki needs fixing.